# Ability to map received data from Firebase as a custom Class using $firebaseObject.extend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a class like this one:

```
class Group {
    constructor(snapshot) {
        var rawData = snapshot.val();
        this.__data__ = angular.copy(rawData);
        this.__id__ = snapshot.key;
    }

    update(rawData) {
        var oldData = angular.extend({}, this.__data__);
        this.__data__ = angular.copy(rawData);

        return !angular.equals(rawData, oldData);
    }

    toJSON() {
        return $firebaseUtils.toJSON(this.__data__);
    }

    get sensorsType() {
        // specific to that class logic to determine what type of sensors objects this group include
    }

    get name() {
        return this.__data__.name || "No name";
    }

   // a lot of other properties and methods further are omitted 
}
```

I extended $firebaseArray with next code:

```
function SyncedGroups(
    $rootScope,
    $firebaseArray
) {
    return $firebaseArray.$extend({
        $$added: function(snapshot) {
            var group = new Group(snapshot);
            $rootScope.$emit('groups-item-added', group);

            return group;
        },

        $$updated: function(snapshot) {
            var group = this.$getRecord(snapshot.key);
            var updated = group.update(snapshot.val());

            if (updated) {
                $rootScope.$emit('groups-item-changed', group);
            }

            return updated;
        }
    });
}
```

And i create extended $firebaseArray like this:

```
    return new SyncedGroups(pathDetails.reference); // in pathDetails.reference could be *.Query
```

Everything works great with $firebaseArray, i query groups from firebase, receive array of Object  type Group:

```
[Group, Group, Group, Group, Group, Group, Group]
```

And every Group object has methods and properties from defined Class.

I would like to make similar manipulations with $firebaseObject, on receive data from Firebase, create Group with passed snapshot and return that object as it was done in $$added of $firebaseArray.extend. But $firebaseObject don't have $$added and $$updated is not triggered if i have next extend setting for $firebaseObject:

```
function SyncedGroup(
    $rootScope,
    $firebaseObject
) {
    return $firebaseObject.$extend({
        $$updated: function(snapshot) {
            var updated = $firebaseObject.prototype.$$updated.apply(this, arguments);

            if (updated) {
                $rootScope.$emit('groups-item-changed', this);
            }

            return updated;
        }
    });
}
```

When use above code, on use of $firebaseArray i get array of objects of type Group - and this is very useful for me, case this object has many useful properties and functions related to that specific class.
But when i use $firebaseObject i get:

```
ChildClass{
   $$conf:Object,
   $id:"group-2",
   $priority:null,
   name:"Kitchen",
   sensors:Object,
   __proto__: Object {
       $$updated: function $$updated(snapshot),
       constructor: function(ref),
       //.....
   }
}
```

Could anyone help me to find a way to create objects of specific Class with $firebaseObject?
Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: This may be of help. https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#extending-firebaseobject